# How to manipulate this?

Tags: manipulate, vector-calculus

I tried to code this, but everytime I code I failed. 
Im not sure what I did wrong and Im fairly new to Mathematica. Can you guys check it out?

```
​Clear[t, x, y, P, velvector, vel, scalefactor];
scalefactor = 0.5;
P[t_] = {t Sin[t], t^2/15};
curveplot = ParametricPlot[P[t], {t,0,10}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01],
            AxesLabel -> {"x", "y","z"}];
vel[t_] = D[P[t], t];
velvector[t_] := Vector[vel[t], Tail -> P[t], VectorColor -> Red,
                 ScaleFactor -> scalefactor];
Manipulate[Show[curveplot[t], 
           Table[velvector[t]], PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, 
           AspectRatio -> 1], {t, 1, 10}]
```